# Update product programmatically not updating quantity in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am updating a Configurable product to just set quantity.but it keeps showing 0 in admin and not updating it.

```
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => 32, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
```

Comment: configurable product  does not have own Qty and its qty is  its child products

Comment: So amit what should i set while saving a configurable product.When i leave configurable blank while saving programmaticly it does not make it out of stock.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to update stock.

```
$product->setStockData(array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
    'manage_stock'=>1,
    'min_sale_qty'=>1,
    'max_sale_qty'=>1000,
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => '170'
));
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Unfortunately its not working.

Comment: Add your entire code

Comment: can i make product out of stock by putting this code $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => 0, 'is_in_stock' => 0]);

Comment: As i want to out of stock the configurable product